# Filas en blanco mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas,

Estoy formando un formulario en php para un sorteo. He conectado mi formulario con la base de datos y todo correcto

Mi problema es que al registrarme los datos que pasa a la base de datos estan en blanco:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Paso el codigo de conexion tambien(no tiene los datos de conexion por seguiridad)

```
    if (!$db_connection) {
    die('No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos');
}

$subs_email = $_POST['Direccion de Correo'];
$subs_nombre = $_POST['Nombre Completo'];
$subs_facebook = $_POST['Perfil Facebook'];

$resultado=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$db_table_name." WHERE email = '".$subs_email."'", $db_connection);

if (mysql_num_rows($resultado)>0)
{

header('Location: fail.html');

} else {

    $insert_value = 'INSERT INTO `' . $db_name . '`.`'.$db_table_name.'` (`email` , `nombre` , `facebook`) VALUES ("' . $subs_email . '", "' . $subs_nombre . '", "' . $subs_facebook . '")';

mysql_select_db($db_name, $db_connection);
$retry_value = mysql_query($insert_value, $db_connection);

if (!$retry_value) {
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

header('Location: sucess.html');
}

mysql_close($db_connection);
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que escribas en tu pregunta el código para ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Ya verificaste que existan los valores post  con un `isset`?

Comment: A que te refieres exactamente , gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estoy muy seguro de que puedas tener espacios al recibir tus variables:

```
$subs_email = $_POST['Direccion de Correo'];
$subs_nombre = $_POST['Nombre Completo'];
$subs_facebook = $_POST['Perfil Facebook'];
```

Deberias de modificar donde envias con guiones bajos para recibirlos así:

```
$subs_email = $_POST['Direccion_de_Correo'];
$subs_nombre = $_POST['Nombre_Completo'];
$subs_facebook = $_POST['Perfil_Facebook'];
```

Comment: Perdona pero no entiendo lo que me quieres decir :( Gracias

Comment: Me refiero a que en tu arreglo $POST los indices ['Direccion de Correo'] no pueden llevar espacios deberias de tener en cambio algo así ['Direccion_de_Correo'] y digo que asi lo deberias de tener en donde lo envias como en donde lo recibes.

Comment: Gracias, no era eso exactamente pero no estaba poniendo los indices correctamente pero gracias a eso me di cuenta , perdonen las molestias